# Peer review creation of new tags

Tags: feature-request, review

When going through the tags, I noticed that several users with the ability to create tags will create tags -- and if there is any description at all, it's often poorly described -- out of nowhere.

Wouldn't it be better to have these new instantaneous tag creations moderated by review? What is the ideology behind letting people with 1500 or more rep just instantaneously create tags?

Comment: New tag creations appear in a special page in the 10k tools, I believe.

Comment: Oh, I just noted a strong correlation between new tags and new posts of the same subject and supposed that the tag creation was related to the post. I tried this myself to create a tag 'blablabla' and it said: "You must have 1500 reputation to create new tags."

Comment: Oh yes, believe me, there are *plenty* of us that monitor the new tag list.  About a third to half of all new tags are totally worthwhile.  The rest are either vague / useless / meta, typos, or tags that already exist under a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New tags show up in the 10k tools (in the "stats" link).  So they aren't moderated before being created, but the information is available to higher-rep users.  Also in the tools you can see what's been recently protected, closed, reopened, deleted, or undeleted, and which posts are attracting the most votes, views, and comments.  It's pretty handy as a way to get a quick "highlights" view of recent activity.

*Most* things on Stack Exchange are not moderated before the fact.  Edits are because they're a source of spam, but just as new posts and comments don't need to be approved first, new tags don't.  In all of these cases the philosophy is to let the material get posted first and then, if needed, the community can act on it.  Communities count on the 10k users to do these reviews from time to time; if crap is getting through on your site, it's probably time to remind people that their help is needed (on meta or in chat).